# Javascript Regular Expression detect all the Phone Number from the page source

Tags: javascript, regex, phone-number

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?
My current one is (I find it on somewhere):

`/(\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7)[0-9. -]{4,14})(?:\b|x\d+)/`

It can detect: +86-400-660-8680

But not this:

- +1 888 204 3539
- 1-800-667-6389
- +1-400-660-8680
- (877) 359-6695
- 800-692-7753

Can you help me with this? 1 Regular Expression can detect all of these kind of phone number or at least I can use 2-3 Regular Expressions to detect them.

Comment: Could you list out every type of phone number that you need found?  Also what are you doing with them?

Answer (score 6):

So here's the huge regex that will match your needs:

> (+?(?:(?:9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)|((?:9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)))[0-9. -]{4,14})(?:\b|x\d+)

**[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/gX3yO5)**

And [here](http://regex101.com/r/nZ5vP8)'s how I did to make it.

Comment: Great link to how you made it

Answer (score 6):

Your regex goes through a lot of trouble to make sure the country code matches a strict set of rules but seems to not care what follows it. Which means the following examples would be matched by it:

```
+86-0000
+86----0
+86-1-1-1-1
```

The following regex is much shorter, is not as strict on the country code but is strict on the overall structure of the phone number.

```
(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[- (]*(\d{3})[- )]*(\d{3})[- ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\b
```

It would not match the examples above and would match these examples:

```
18005551234
1 800 555 1234
+1 800 555-1234
+86 800 555 1234
1-800-555-1234
1 (800) 555-1234
(800)555-1234
(800) 555-1234
(800)5551234
800-555-1234
800 555 1234x5678
8005551234 x5678
1    800    555-5555
1----800----555-5555
```

For all these examples, the capture groups would contain the following values:

- Group1: Country Code (ex: 1 or 86)
- Group2: Area Code (ex: 800)
- Group3: Exchange (ex: 555)
- Group4: Subscriber Number (ex: 1234)
- Group5: Extension (ex: 5678)